# Unable to get image from file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

```
pubspec.yaml

google_sign_in: ^4.1.4
apple_sign_in:
    path: /home/Desktop/temp/apps/Apple/flutter_apple_sign_in/

PUB of flutter_apple_sign_in
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  plugin:
     androidPackage: dev.gilder.tom.apple_sign_in
     pluginClass: AppleSignInPlugin
  assets:
     -  images/


//Following is code

class _AppleSignInButtonState extends State<AppleSignInButton> {
  bool _isTapDown = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bgColor =
        widget.style == ButtonStyle.black ? Colors.black : Colors.white;
    final textColor =
        widget.style == ButtonStyle.black ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
    final borderColor =
        widget.style == ButtonStyle.white ? Colors.white : Colors.black;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => setState(() => _isTapDown = true),
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() => _isTapDown = false);
        widget?.onPressed();
      },
      onTapCancel: () => setState(() => _isTapDown = false),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(widget.cornerRadius),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: widget.type == ButtonType.continueButton
              ? Image.asset("images/white_outlined.png")
              : Image.asset("images/getapple.jpg") //Here I am using jpg
        ),
        width: double.infinity,
      ),
    );
  }
}


Error
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (32764): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (32764): Unable to load asset: images/getapple.jpg
I/flutter (32764): 
I/flutter (32764): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (32764): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (32764): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (32764): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
I/flutter (32764): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
```

**Here I am using flutter_apple_sign_in package in the local directory,
I am using ubuntu,
I want to modify the UI of that package,
so I forked it.
And While I am accessing that package,I am unable to access images and getting the above error.

I have attached the screenshot below.

**[image]

Comment: Have you declared your images / assets into pubspec.yaml ?
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: Yes it is in the pubspec.yaml. @Danaru

Answer (score 2):

In ***pubspec.yaml***

you need to declare your images assets

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/getapple.jpg
```

or To include all of your image files in your folder

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

if it not showing try to stop and run your program again.